# How to make Dockerfile for e2e tests written with Puppeteer

Tags: docker, dockerfile, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I use an amazing tool called [Puppetry](https://electronjs.org/apps/puppetry) to create e2e tests. The tests are run using npm command - `npm test`. Easy peasy.

I run these tests in the deployment pipeline using a Dockerfile. Everything works okay. 
**What I'd like to know is which of these 2 approaches is better (and why):**

```
# Dockerfile 
# other docker instructions

RUN npm run test  <== 1. running tests when the image builds
CMD npm test <== 2. running tests after the image builds
```

Presently, I use 2nd approach.

Some more info:

My deployment pipeline looks like this:

**BuildDev > DeployDev >TestDev**

BuildDev uses build Dockerfile. TestDev uses test Dockerfile.

Comment: second to @David, good to go with the second approach, you will not able to communicate with other container using the first approach.

Comment: @Adiii both approaches work in my pipeline. The tests start with opening my React application in a headless chromium instance.

Comment: Actually during build does not make sense, image is just a template and you do not have such functionality which a running container can provide. there is tone of thing that you can not perform during build process

Comment: @Adiii I've added my pipeline setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t run end-to-end tests from a Dockerfile `RUN` command.  It’s run in an environment where there is no persistent storage and the container can’t reach other containers.  (Technically speaking, there are no external volume mounts and it runs on the default bridge network.)  That means, if the system under test is running in Docker, the test build can’t reach it, and in any case the results can’t be recorded anywhere other than the built image.

This is also a good candidate for something to run from outside of Docker.  Frequently end-to-end tests will only call a system’s externally visible endpoints and validate the behavior that’s observable that way.  That means that you don’t need to call random containers within your stack, only the one nginx proxy container you’re publishing; there’s no specific need to be on the Docker-internal network.  You’ll also want to get published results out, and Docker’s filesystem isolation can get in your way, and can want to re-run tests with minor tweaks (and not re-`docker build`).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've added my pipeline setup in the question if that gives some more info. Please note that my tests run successfully in either approaches.